# Union type error in spring boot with graphql java kickstart

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I have problem with union in graphql, I try to make tutorial with graphql and I stuck in one error

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.UnionTypeResolver.<init>(DictionaryTypeResolver.kt:41)

The following method did not exist:

    'java.lang.String graphql.schema.GraphQLOutputType.getName()'
```

This is my union defined in graphqls

```
type Talk {
    id : ID!
    title : String
    description : String
    speakers : [ Speaker ]
}

type Speaker {
    id : ID!
    name : String
    twitter : String
}

union All = Speaker | Talk

type Query {
    allAll : [All]
}
```

This is my resolver for method allAll

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MemberQueryResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    private final SpeakerService speakerService;
    private final TalkService talkService;

    public List<Object> allAll() {
        var list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.addAll(speakerService.findAll());
        list.addAll(talkService.findAll());
        return list;
    }
}
```

And this is my config schema method

```
private GraphQLSchema buildSchema(TalkService talkService, AttendeeService attendeeService,
                                      SpeakerService speakerService) {
        return SchemaParser
                .newParser()
                .file("graphql/schema.graphqls")
                .resolvers(
                        new MemberQueryResolver(speakerService, talkService)
                )
                .build()
                .makeExecutableSchema();
    }
```

When i remove resolver i am getting error that method for allAll mapping does not exist but when i register resolver with this method spring server crash with above error. Has anyone try to do union types with java kickstart and can show me issue or my mistake ?

Comment: assuming this method `buildSchema` should be public

Comment: Nope this schema is used in bean definition so it is not important to make this method public